# Use of も in this sentence: パブもシティーセンターも静かになります。

Tags: grammar, particles

This is the sentence in question from one of my text books.

> 学生がいませんから、パブもシティーセンターも静かになります。

My Translation - "There are no students so the pubs and city centre become quiet."

Why is it も and not と separating パブ and シティーセンター and then another も before 静か which I don't understand at all?

Comment: [weblio辞書](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/A%E3%82%82B%E3%82%82) says "AもBも = both A and B"

Comment: 「シティーセンター」って都心ってこと？

Comment: 「中心街」とかかな。（アメリカではdowntown、イギリスではcity centreって言うって聞いたんだけど・・・ホンマかどうかは知らな～い）

Comment: 場所の名前だったりして。これとか　http://www.shiodomecitycenter.com/

Comment: It's a textbook, so my guess would be that シティーセンター indeed refers to the "city centre" (中心街) and the textbook authors chose シティーセンター, because it would be easily understood by beginners.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, ～も～も (with a positive verb) corresponds usually to the construction "both ... and ..." in English. The Japanese construction is not limited to two nouns, but one has ～も～も～も (which might be "all of ..., ... and ..." in English).

I understand the construction to be "not restrictive" in the sense that ～も～も can mean "both ... and ... and a bunch of other ...". On the other hand ～と～ suggest "exactly ... and ...". So here

> 学生がいませんから、パブもシティーセンターも静かになります。
> Because there are no students, pubs, the city centre *and everything else* become quiet.
>
> 学生がいませんから、パブとシティーセンターが静かになります。
> Because there are no students, particularly pubs and the city centre become quiet *although everywhere else business is as usual*.

Comment: So could the translation just be "because there are no students both the pubs and city centre becomes quiet" or is the "and everything else" sentiment a necessary part of this ～も～も structure?

Comment: I think what he's saying is that the "everything else" is implied. You could also say something like "places like the pubs and city center"