# grammar usage:ｘもｙもｚもあります vs ｘとｙとｚはあります

Tags: grammar, particle-と, particle-も

I read the first sentence in a graded reader, and I'm wondering why the author chose the first grammar pattern over the second.

絵本{えほん｝**も**ピアノ**も**テレビ**も**あります。

絵本**と**ピアノ**と**テレビ**が**あります。

What is the difference in meaning between these two phrases, or, if the meaning is relatively similar, why would you choose to use one over the other?

Comment: `絵本とピアノとテレビはあります。` <-- You'd use が as in 「絵本とピアノとテレビ**が**あります。」 to mean "There are ~~~" in normal situations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See in depth explanation: [Use of も in this sentence.](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14132/use-of-%E3%82%82-in-this-sentence)

In brief

- 絵本**も**ピアノ**も**テレビ**も**あります translates roughly to "There are *(many things such as)* picture books, a piano, and a television."
- 絵本**と**ピアノ**と**テレビ**が**あります translates roughly to "There is a picture book, a piano, and a television *(and that's exactly it)."*