# Is this usage of も and sentence correct?

Tags: particle-も

So I am learning uses of the particle も, and one of my methods is to make example sentences to solidify its use. I was wondering if the sentence 少し**も**その映画を見られなかった correctly means “I couldn’t **even** see a little bit of that movie.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The translation of the example above is correct. However, there are other uses of も particle than the example you should be aware of such as [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14132/use-of-%e3%82%82-in-this-sentence-%e3%83%91%e3%83%96%e3%82%82%e3%82%b7%e3%83%86%e3%82%a3%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bb%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%bc%e3%82%82%e9%9d%99%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ab%e3%81%aa%e3%82%8a%e3%81%be%e3%81%99), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58433/%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%ae%e3%82%82%e5%bd%93%e7%84%b6%e3%81%a0-use-of-%e3%82%82-to-soften), [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58411/%e3%82%82-particle-exclamation-special-usage-%e3%82%82-%e3%81%a8-nuance-distinction), [this](https://m.japanesemeow.com/japanese-grammar-lessons/adding-nouns-together-mo-to-and-ya/), [this](https://bondlingo.tv/blog/japanese-particles-%E3%82%82-mo-and-%E3%81%A8-to/), [this](https://www.punipunijapan.com/mo/) and [this](http://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/01/21/the-wonders-of-japanese-particle-%E3%82%82mo-different-ways-to-say-also-intermediate/).